# R Given a column, find duplicates of this column in a data.frame

Tags: r

Given the following data:

```
questionTagMatrix <- data.frame( question1=c("0","1","0"), question2=c("1","0", "0"), question3=c("0","1","0"), question4=c("0","1","1")  )
rownames(questionTagMatrix)[1] <- "php"
rownames(questionTagMatrix)[2] <- "html"
rownames(questionTagMatrix)[3] <- "javascript"

newQuestion <- data.frame( newquestion=c("0","1","0") )
rownames(newQuestion)[1] <- "php"
rownames(newQuestion)[2] <- "html"
rownames(newQuestion)[3] <- "javascript"
```

How do I find all columns of `questionTagMatrix` equal to `newQuestion`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply` to find the columns:

```
questionTagMatrix[apply(questionTagMatrix, 2, function(x) 
                                               all(x == as.matrix(newQuestion)))]
```

All columns of `questionTagMatrix` are compared with `newQuestion`. The result:

```
#            question1 question3
# php                0         0
# html               1         1
# javascript         0         0
```

Answer (score 0):

A vectorized solution using `colSums`:

```
 questionTagMatrix[,colSums(questionTagMatrix == newQuestion)
                    ==nrow(questionTagMatrix)]

          question1 question3
php                0         0
html               1         1
javascript         0         0
```

PS newQuestion is a vector here :

```
newQuestion =c("0","1","0") ## not data.frame( newquestion=c("0","1","0") )
```

To get only questions names:

```
names(questionTagMatrix)[colSums(questionTagMatrix == newQuestion)
+                   ==nrow(questionTagMatrix)]
[1] "question1" "question3"
```

Comment: I get an error: "Error in Ops.data.frame(questionTagMatrix, newQuestion) etc."

Comment: @tucson see my edit. No need to put newQuestion in a data.frame, keep it as a vector.